# Makefile blank arguments causing errors in shell

Tags: c++, c, bash, shell, makefile

So I'm writing a general makefile to compile C/C++ programs. There is a selection of variables you can fill in, and I'd like the option to leave them blank. However, if I leave them blank, it causes some errors in a shell search I have later in.

Eg:

```
FILESDIR = 
FILES = $(shell find $(FILESDIR) -type -f -name "*.cpp")
NOTFILES = $(shell find . -not -path *$(FILESDIR)* -type f - name "*.cpp")
```

This however will throw an error. I'm guessing it's because the shell line is evaluated to `shell find -type -name "*.cpp"`, which is syntactically wrong.

My current work around is to assign `FILESDIR = /dev/null`, but I'd like to be able to leave it blank.

How can I make a check, or better my shell search so it can accomodate empty lines?

Comment: What case would be valid where there are no files to process?

Comment: I have some 3rd party stuff that doesn't need to recompile every time I `make clean`. So it's pretty much setting up an 'ignore' file. It's not always applicable though.

Comment: What should it mean to find files in a directory that doesn't exist? If I ask you to list all the giraffes in nowhere, I shouldn't be surprised if you respond that my question is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

this posted makefile contents:

```
FILESDIR = 
FILES = $(shell find $(FILESDIR) -type -f -name "*.cpp")
NOTFILES = $(shell find . -not -path *$(FILESDIR)* -type f - name "*.cpp")
```

Has a few problems, as you have noticed.

A better implementation might be:

```
FILESDIR = .     
FILES := $(wildcard  $(FILESDIR)/*.cpp )
NOTFILES := $(shell find . -not -path *$(FILESDIR)/* -type f -name "*.cpp")
```

Then the macro `FILESDIR` can be overridden via a `-D` parameter on the make invocation line.

Comment: Will `wildcard` search recursively?

Comment: `wildcard` is one of the `make` built-ins.   with no directory specified, It searches the current directory, with a directory specified, it searches that directory.  it does not perform a recursive search into sub directories.   Suggest reading a tutorial on the `make` utility, such as this one: <http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html>